# AJAX - how do I protect my ajax/php functions from being spammed?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm currently redesigning my site - it is a game arcade with over 2,000 flash games. I had the site designed/created for me years ago and I've taken it upon myself to modernise it.
I've come upon a particular problem that I'm concerned about, in the past the site has been attacked by hackers and at one point it was vulnerable to mysql injection, but it's since been fixed.
Here's the problem though - the current site uses excessive PHP. I don't like this so I thought I'd try and reduce a lot of server strain by using javascript where necessary.  For instance, it often needs to retrieve a list of games from the database.
I'm using Jquery's post() function to deliver an array of ids to a php called 'get-games.php'
a bit like this:

```
$.post( "ajax/get-games.php", { ids:ids } , function( data ) {
  //create games list with response data
});
```

What's to stop someone maliciously calling this function with 500 ids repeatedly? There's an obvious answer - in the get-games.php add something like:

```
if (ids.length > 100) throw an error
```

But occasionally I might want to retrieve a list of >100 games, perhaps on the admin panel. It just seems a bit limiting and I wonder if there's a better way of approaching this kind of spammable functionality.

Comment: You can implement a per-IP rate limit.

Comment: you may also implement a caching stategy for oftenly used requests. And some logical tests on the array of `ids` like a max length.

Comment: @Barmar Can you pls recommend some tutorials or code examples?

Comment: Side question - is it good practice to have different actions for different phps? So in my example above I used 'ajax/get-games.php' - what if I had a more general php which contained all necessary functions like 'ajax.php' that would serve every ajax request, would that be more efficient?
Otherwise I'll no doubt need to use a lot of 'includes' when ajax functions references one another.

Answer (score 1):

There's no magic bullet, sadly, you're likely to have to implement a range of measures, enforced server-side:

- Rate limits (e.g., per IP) of various kinds (depends on the patterns of use of your site)
- Only allow small requests except from known admin sessions
- Possibly lock down the IPs from which admins sessions are allowed
- If the UI of the site only allows action X after action Y, server-side deny action X if the session in question hasn't previously done action Y within the relevant time

...and so on. The Stack Exchange system has been playing whack-a-mole with these sorts of things for years (quite successfully), so it can be done, but you'll have to be vigilant and watch the patterns of use on the site for abuses, and then introduce new measures to curtail those abuses...

Comment: Can you explain about Rate limits or any tutorials

Comment: @IndraKumarS: I don't know of any tutorials, but the general concept of a rate limit is to only allow action X from source Y *n* number of times within time *t*. Here's an example: Try to post two comments on this question, one right after another. The SE system won't let you, it tells you you have to wait 15 seconds between comments (and resets the timer). Similarly, you can't delete comments faster than one every five seconds. Those are the simplest kind, but there are other kinds, like not allowing someone to load game 1 more than five times in 10 minutes, that kind of thing.

Comment: It's a good answer, i would also add caching to the list, so repeat queries can be served without hitting the stack.

Comment: How would query caching best be done? Session variables perhaps?